# Expanding the Following Grassmann Function

Tags: condensed-matter, grassmann-numbers

I am reading Altland and Simons, and they perform the following step in a calculation I am not sure how to perform. If $a_i$ and $\bar{\eta}_i$ are Grassmann variables, then

$$e^{-\sum_i a_i \bar{\eta}_i} = \prod_i (1-a_i \bar{\eta}_i).$$

I can see how this might be true if we could write $e^{-\sum_i a_i \bar{\eta}_i} = e^{-a_1 \bar{\eta}_1}e^{-a_2 \bar{\eta}_2}...$, and then expand each of the exponentials individually. However, it does not seem like the $a_i\bar{\eta}_i$ terms do not commute, so we cannot do that. So how does one get this formula?

Comment: Which page in A&S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_i, \bar{\eta}_i$ are Grassmann-odd then their product $a_i \bar{\eta_i}$ is Grassmann-even so

$$ [a_i\bar{\eta}_i , a_j \bar{\eta}_j] = 0 $$
which allows you to make the manipulation with exponentials indicated in the OP.

---

Proof of the above:

$$a_i \bar{\eta}_i a_j \bar{\eta}_j = - a_i a_j \bar{\eta}_i \bar{\eta}_j = + a_i a_j \bar{\eta}_j \bar{\eta}_i = - a_j a_i \bar{\eta}_j \bar{\eta}_i = a_j \bar{\eta}_j a_i \bar{\eta}_i$$

Answer (score 2):

What about this?
\begin{equation}
e^{-\sum_i a_i\bar\eta_i}=\prod_ie^{-a_i\bar\eta_i}=\prod_i(1-a_i\bar\eta_i)~,
\end{equation}
since $a_i^2,\bar\eta_i^2=0$.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what OP says they wanted to do but weren't sure of the justification for the first step?

Comment: @jacob1729 well, it can be viewed as simply a consequence of the nilpotency of the grassmann numbers which in turn is a consequence of their anticommuting nature

Comment: Ah I typed too quickly - I had read your final comment as applying to the second equality not the first...